# Switch power ratings to control multiple RGB diodes

Tags: voltage, switches, diodes, amperage

I will be using 6 RGB common anodes in parallel setting.
I will be connecting the diodes on a car speaker and will need a switch to toggle between colors.

Voltage supply is 12V(or 13,5V), with a FW current of 20mA and FW supply of 2V,3V,3V (red,green,blue respectevly) for each diode

I need help choosing the right switch that can handle the voltage and Ampers.

i found this
[image]

The switch can handle 0.05A/50mA, Will it be sufficient for my project?
If not, What power/ampere rating switch shauld i look for for my application.

Edit:

This is how i will wire them(+ resistors) Sorry for bad representation.
[image]

Comment: This can't be answered unless you draw a schematic of how you want to wire them.

Comment: @HandyHowie I appolagize, i added the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will have a current of 20mA (full brightness) per LED you can't use this switch. One switch has to deal with 120mA (6*20mA), which is more than twice of the allowed maximum. You can use bigger Resistors, to limit the current to ~8mA per LED if it isn't a problem for you to have them shine darker.
Otherwise you need a switch with a rating of atleast 120mA.

Fitting Resistors, calculated by 13.5V would be:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! That is a clear and understandable answer.
May i ask, how darker would the lights be at 8mA.

Comment: That completly depends on the LED itself. Some will shine only a little bit darker and others will be nearly gone. Just test it on a breadboard and look if it fits your needs.

Comment: @FlawlezzJaxy Added the Resistor table, so you could test it faster.

Comment: Thank you, i already calculated the resistors for 20mA beforehand.  
Is choosing 13.5V supply the correct choise when dealing with a car?

May i ask what does E12 and E24 mean?

Comment: @FlawlezzJaxy I don't know the exact Voltage of a fully charged car battery, but its better to calculate with a higher, than a smaller voltage. The E12 and E24 means the "resistor row". It is an indicator for the tolerance and the available values (E24 is more accurate and has more values available). You can find more infos here: http://www.resistorguide.com/resistor-values/    For your purpose it isn't important, which you choose.

Comment: Ok thank you, got my answer. Looking for a 12v+ and 120mA+ switch. (i can run 12V switch on a car electronics even if its sometimes acully 13.5V or shauld i rather search 24v+)?

Comment: As a responsible person i would say anything with 14V or higher is good. As the man who I am, i say that 12V rating is enough.

Comment: would this one be sufficiant?

http://si.farnell.com/grayhill/76sb03t/switch-spst-3-pos-raised-rocker/dp/1608114#anchorTechnicalDOCS

It says 30V and 150mA, but under pdf there are some confusing informations for me


http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1884225.pdf

im only asking because im confused at:
1 mA, 5 Vdc; 50 mA, 30 Vdc; or 150 mA, 30 Vdc:
10 mA, 30 Vdc; or 10 mA, 50 mVdc:
10 mA, 50 mVdc; or 25 mA, 24 Vdc; or 100 mA, 6 Vdc:

Comment: I think there are different types of these switches. You can see that the one from farnell is listed along the values. So i would say it is no Problem to take this switch.

Comment: Yeah it is listed for 30V and 150mA, but the description in the pdf  file is abit confusing. ill probbly take this one. thank.